# Where is the dc=example,dc=com ldap dit?

Tags: server, ldap

I am following the server guide for ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am trying to setup ldap but I have a problem. There is supposed to be a dit named `dc=example,dc=com` but when I type `ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=example,dc=com dn` I get `No such object (32)` instead of

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

like the guide says i should.

Now after making the `add_content.ldif` file with the contents listed in the guide and use the command `ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f add_content.ldif` with the password I set during installation I get `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`.

So i guess there is no `dc=example,dc=com` ldap dit so where is it or how do I make it so i can follow the guide?

Comment: I assume you're talking about https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html?

Comment: I am using the pdf version at [https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf) but yes.

Comment: When you installed `slapd`, it would have asked you for a DN. What value did you give it?

Comment: It did not ask for a DN just a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked `slapd` installation on a VM, and it does not create an example DN by default (which is a good thing):

```
$ ls /etc/ldap/slapd.d
cn=config cn=config.ldif
```

You can either add entries all the way from a base DN, or run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd`, in which case, you will be greeted with these choices:

- Pick *No*:
  [image: Do not skip slapd configuration]
- Use an FQDN (such as `example.com`, `my.personal.site.org`, etc.):
  [image: Enter an FQDN]
  Do NOT enter `dc=example,dc=com` here.
- Pick some name (e.g.,  "An example site", "My personal site", etc.):
  [image: Enter your domain's pretty name]
- When asked for admin password, you're resetting the password to `cn=admin,cn=config`. So it's not necessary that you use the password you set while installing `slapd`.
- Use HDB unless you *know* otherwise. If you don't know what this is, HDB it is.
  [image: Pick HDB]
- Since we don't have a database, pick yes.
  [image: Purge it all]
- Same here. Move it.
  [image: Move everything]
- Do not allow v2 unless you *know* otherwise. If you don't know what this is, *No* it is.
  [image: LDAPv3 only]

A base DN for whatever FQDN you entered will be created.

You can repeated `sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd` to reset `slapd` and start over from scratch at any time.